# Unable to make a custom dialog for Spritekit swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently having a problem with making a popup dialog for the spritekit game. What I want to do is to show a custom dialog that shows up when the game start button is pressed. I was able to make the custom dialog , but the problem is how to make a button for this custom dialog that extends a UIView to transition to the other Scene ?  This code below will make the dialog apear in the title scene when the start button is selected

```
let dialog = CustomDialog(scene: self, frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view!.bounds.maxX - 50, 300))
    self.view!.addSubview(dialog)
```

But how can I implement this script within the CustomDialog class ?

```
 let scene = GameStartedScene(size: self.size)
            scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
            skview.presentScene(scene)
```

The code below is the CustomDialog class , Is there a way to make this class to transition to other scene ? Since I'm new to swift and spritekit , It would be a honor if I can have some sample or hints.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class CustomDialog : UIView{

    var backGroundView : UIView!
    var scene : SKScene!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init(scene : SKScene,frame : CGRect){
        super.init(frame: scene.view!.bounds)


        self.scene = scene


        self.scene.view!.paused = true


        self.scene.userInteractionEnabled = false

        self.layer.zPosition = 10


        self.backGroundView = UIView(frame: scene.view!.bounds)
        self.backGroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.3)
        self.backGroundView.layer.position = scene.view!.center
        self.addSubview(backGroundView)


        let board = UIView(frame: frame)
        board.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        board.layer.position = backGroundView.center
        board.layer.masksToBounds = true
        board.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        board.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        self.addSubview(board)


        let textView = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200,50))
        textView.text = "hogehoge"
        textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        textView.layer.position = backGroundView.center
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        textView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.addSubview(textView)


        let myWindowExitButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.ContactAdd) as! UIButton
        myWindowExitButton.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        myWindowExitButton.layer.position = CGPointMake(board.bounds.maxX - myWindowExitButton.bounds.midX - 5, myWindowExitButton.bounds.midY + 5)

                   myWindowExitButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat((45.0 * M_PI) / 180.0))

        myWindowExitButton.addTarget(self, action: "onExitButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        board.addSubview(myWindowExitButton)

    }

    func onExitButton(sender : UIButton){

        self.scene.view!.paused = false
        self.scene.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.removeFromSuperview()

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do transitions in SprieKit? If you are, look at "theNewBoston"'s channel on YouTube on transitioning in swift SpriteKit. Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15TcLdEbhrE&index=33&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDgp7nGSUnnXihbTLFZJ79B

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out when I have time!